# Process execution time and performance using various dispatch queues and NSOperationQueue

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa

I have a XML in my App bundle. I am parsing this XML file. I parsed this XML using `NSXMLParser` and using following ways:

1. running the whole code serially on main thread
2. Using dispatch queues (GCD):

   2.1 Creating my own dispatch queue using **dispatch_queue_create**

   2.2 using global queue with High Priority **dispatch_get_global_queue**

   2.3 using global queue with Low Priority

   2.4 using global queue with Background Priority
3. using `NSOperationQueue`

I checked the performance and total time taken in execution of parsing the XML file and found  really weird (or may be correct) results.

Following are the codes for above mentioned Parsing ways:

1. Serial execution on main thread - Execution time **34 msec.**

   ```
   BOOL success = [conf parseXMLFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Configuration" ofType:@"xml"] didFailWithError:&error];
   if (success) {
       DLog(@"Parsing Complete");
   }
   else
       DLog(@"Parse error %@",[error description]);
   ```

2.1 Using **dispatch_queue_create** - Execution time **68 msec**.

```
dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_queue_create("BackQueue", NULL);

dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{
    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL success = [conf parseXMLFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Configuration" ofType:@"xml"] didFailWithError:&error];
    if (success) {
        DLog(@"Parsing Complete");
    }
    else
        DLog(@"Parse error %@",[error description]);
});

dispatch_release(backgroundQueue);
```

2.2 using global queue with High Priority **dispatch_get_global_queue** - Execution time - **74 msec**

```
dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);

dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{
    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL success = [conf parseXMLFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Configuration" ofType:@"xml"] didFailWithError:&error];
    if (success) {
        DLog(@"Parsing Complete");
    }
    else
        DLog(@"Parse error %@",[error description]);
});

dispatch_release(backgroundQueue);
```

2.3 Similarly as 2.2 Using global queue with LOW Priority **DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW** - Execution time - **72 msec**

2.4 Similarly as 2.2 Using global queue with BACKGROUND Priority **DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND** - Execution time - **37 msec**

2.5. Using `NSOperationQueue` (subclassing the NSOperation) - Execution time - **36 msec**

Can anyone help me figure out these execution times and why are they so strange (or am I missing something). Why I am getting the best performance with method 1. 
Why is DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND giving better performance than HIGH. 
Why is NSOperationQueue giving better results than GCD?

Comment: Three thoughts: 1. Are your benchmarks for the whole process, or just what's taking place inside the `dispatch_async`. It would be interesting to know how processing times inside the queue compared to the whole process (so that you can differentiate between processing time and sundry queue configuration management time). Your answer may rest in there. 2. How many times did you run this test? You want to make sure you're not assessing the performance on the basis of one run. 3. Are you benchmarking on a device or the simulator? The former would be far more meaningful.

Comment: how big is your XML file? if your file is small and the parsing time is as little as 34 ms, you should just parse it on main thread as there is overhead on creating threads.
Try parsing a lot of big XML files to see the difference. There is no big different if you are just parsing one small file. The "time" that you measured does not reflect the actual performance as there maybe other threads working / using CPU time.

Comment: @Owen I will try with some large/ complex XML file and update you. But  what about NSOperationQueue vs GCD and also what about BACKGROUND global vs HIGH global?

Comment: @Rob I ran these test on iPad 2 and like dozens of time and the results are approximately same every time

Comment: As an aside, on your `NSOperationQueue` approach, you mention subclassing `NSOperation`. You don't have to go through all of that. For a single little task like this, [`addOperationWithBlock`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSOperationQueue/addOperationWithBlock:) is a wonderful parallel to `dispatch_async`.

Comment: How many times are you running/dispatching each block? Ideally, you'd log every run time to a file and then take the average and standard deviation using statistics tools or at least a spreadsheet. (`dispatch_barrier` will help you here, for the GCD-based solutions.)

Comment: @PeterHosey I am running each block only once. For calculating the execution time i am using DLog. I calculate the time first DLog prints and the last DLog

Comment: @Rob The codes that you wrote, are they similar to mine or is there any difference.

Comment: @EvolGate I suspect that my XML is larger, and I'm running it repeatedly to try to smooth out variations in the benchmarking, but I suspect we're doing it similar ways. Also, in my updated answer, I benchmark both (a) running 100 parses in a single operation; and (b) submitting 100 operations, each with 1 parse. I've uploaded my [project](https://github.com/robertmryan/nsxmlparser-background-operation-benchmark-1) if you want to look at my source.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:**

I tested the various dispatch and operation queues for for two scenarios:

1. Invoke a single job that repeatedly parse a large (725kb) XML file 100 times in a single operation; and
2. Queue 100 operations to parse the same very large XML file one time each.

My results (measured in seconds) on my iPhone 5 were as follows:

1. For first scenario:

   ```
   Main queue: 18.7
   NSOperation: 18.4
   Global high-priority queue: 18.3
   Global default-priority queue: 18.4
   Global low-priority queue: 18.4
   Global background queue: 18.5
   Serial dispatch queue: 18.3
   ```
2. For my second scenario:

   ```
   Main queue: 18.7
   NSOperation: 10.9
   Global high-priority queue: 10.9
   Global default-priority queue: 10.8
   Global low-priority queue: 10.8
   Global background queue: 11.0
   Serial dispatch queue: 18.5
   ```

So I draw two fairly unsurprising conclusions from this:

- For a computationally intensive background operation at the very least, there did not appear to be much variation between the various concurrent background techniques;
- When breaking a task into multiple operations, the concurrent background operations (`NSOperationQueue`, GCD global queues) enjoyed a performance advantage over the serial operations.

I'm not suggesting, though, that a device under resource contention might not exhibit different behavior in terms of scheduling (notably GCD global queue types, see [`dispatch_queue_priority_t`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/dispatch_queue_priority_t), would affect the scheduling of operations with other concurrent operations queued on the device). I'm only trying to demonstrate empirically that the various queues are not significantly more or less efficient than each other. Having said that, I personally wouldn't use `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH` in my apps as I assume that would have the possibility of affecting core iOS functionality.

Also, in the interest of full disclosure, I should admit that I'm focusing on material performance differences. It is quite possible that one mechanism or another might offer performance differences measured in msec. When I'm considering different approaches for background performance, I'm definitely more focused on user-observable performance differences.

---

**Original Answer:**

I invoked my `parseManyTimes` (which repeatedly parses a large XML file) from the main queue:

```
[self parseManyTimes:@"Main queue"];
```

Via `NSOperation`:

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[queue addOperationWithBlock:^{
     [self parseManyTimes:@"NSOperation"];
}];
queue = nil;
```

Via global queues on GCD:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [self parseManyTimes:@"DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT"];
});
```

and

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
    [self parseManyTimes:@"DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH"];
});
```

and

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
    [self parseManyTimes:@"DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW"];
});
```

and via a GCD serial queue:

```
dispatch_queue_t dispatchQueue = dispatch_queue_create("org.rob.test", NULL);
dispatch_async(dispatchQueue, ^{
    [self parseManyTimes:@"dispatch_queue_create"];
});
```

and the results did not differ significantly from each other (all between 32.2 and 32.5 seconds each). My parsing routine is:

```
- (void)parseManyTimes:(NSString *)type
{
    NSDate *startDate = [NSDate date];
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        [self parse];

    NSLog(@"%@: %.1f", type, [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate]);
}

- (void)parse
{
    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"personnel" withExtension:@"xml"];
    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    parser.delegate = self;
    [parser parse];
}
```

I ran this on an iPad on a 725kb XML file. Clearly, the way I've structured this, with a very time consuming process, it will tend to was out any negligible variance in how the various queues are dispatched, but rather focus on the background operation. By it doesn't raise any concerns (for me at least) in material performance issues in the various techniques.

The results were:

```
Main queue: 32.3
NSOperation: 32.2
DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT: 32.4
DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH: 32.3
DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW: 32.5
dispatch_queue_create: 32.3
```

Comment: This only times the work code, though. Code shouldn't run any faster or slower according to what thread it's on or how it was put there unless the machine is under heavy load (threads contending for processors, in which case priorities *may* come into play—and even then, that may only affect which queues get to call their blocks rather than which threads get the processors). A better method would be to time calling the block n times directly, use an NSBlockOp dependent on n operations to report the time taken with NSOperationQueue, and use `dispatch_barrier` after n `dispatch_async`s for GCD.

Comment: @PeterHosey "That only times the work code, though." That was the entire point of my answer was to point out that the parsing performance, itself, is largely unaffected by the concurrent operation technology you choose. If the OP is concerned about other practical scenarios, he should probably benchmark those specific scenarios. I was just concerned about the sort of conclusions were being implied by the several msec difference between different techniques, without placing it in a broader context.

Comment: @PeterHosey for giggles and grins, I reran the analysis using (a) single operation with 100 NSXMLParser parses; and (b) 100 operations with a single NSXMLSParser parse, and the results were unsurprising. But see my updated answer. (BTW, on the dispatch queues, I used a `dispatch_group_t` to manage the dependencies, not barriers, as I understand one shouldn't use barriers on global queues, which was part of my benchmark. I don't suspect that with only 100 operations barriers would have a material impact, but I'll leave that to others to test if they so choose.)

Comment: One thing to note: NSXMLParser performance can vary quite a bit when you change which delegate methods are implemented.

Comment: @Catfish_Man That's interesting. Which delegate methods are you referring to? It seems that `didStartElement` and `foundCharacters` are essential. Which others are you thinking about that significantly affect performance? (By the way, for those who are concerned about XML parsing performance, this [Ray Wenderlich article](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project) is an interesting read.)

Comment: All of them require some amount of work that can be (and is) avoided when the delegate doesn't implement it. foundCharacters requires additional allocations for the string (and in the typical case, the append to the API client's mutable string) for example.

Comment: @Rob I didn't get a chance to try with large XML and then re-check your results, but I did created a simple SingleView App and checked the same results. Trust me Rob, my results stay intact. There was hardly any difference. I know its in msec, but I still wanna go into deep of this. I'm surprised but I'm going to try with Heavy XML now. Soon I will update you on this.

Comment: @Rob Thanks a lot man. I tried the same tests with the XML you provided in your project file and ran it 100 times and found that results had minimum difference as you mention. So for now I am keeping msec difference out of my mind :)

Answer (score 3):

The performance of the various default concurrent queues is only relative.  "High" priority just means higher than the other queues.  I expect for your synthetic benchmark little else was happening at the time, thus why all the queues appear to perform equivalently.  If you want an actual demonstration of the weighting, enqueue a hundred parse operations to *each* of the concurrent queues, all at once, and compare their times of execution.

Note also that NSOperation uses the default-priority concurrent queue to execute, so as you saw the performance is essentially the same.  At best you're just measuring the overhead of NSOperation, which is tiny.

In your initial results you saw quite different timings.  What were the conditions of those measurements?  For example, if you're performing this at app startup then shifting your XML parsing to another thread or queue could well make it take longer, since your main thread & queue might be contending with it for CPU time.  A better test in that sort of case would be overall launch time, which will demonstrate the benefit of utilising multiple cores.

Comment: This test is just to check the performance. I mean it is simply a SingleView App and the code is written inside viewDidLoad. Moreover, I am doing the test one by one separately with different methods. Also, can you describe more on your statement " XML parsing to another thread or queue could well make it take longer"